# Does adal4j-1.6.2.jar Supported by Open JDK patfrom or not?

Tags: adal

I am going to use the following jar in development of a product:

adal4j-1.6.2.jar

I just want to confirm, whether above mentioned jar is supported by Open JDK or not.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: What is your JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Open JDK supports ADAL4J. However, it is recommended that you use a later version of the jar package. For details, please see: [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j/1.6.2) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

By the way, `ADAL4J` is currently in maintenance mode, except for security fixes, no new features will be added in the future, it is recommended that you migrate to the latest `MSAL4J`. [ADAL to MSAL migration guide for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java).